# Counting days, weeks, months AND weekends between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using momentJS to count number of days between a range of 2 dates. Then, I convert this number in months, weeks and days. I can't make it count weekends. I think I should use isoweek() but it's not working for. It seems to check today's day : var isoweek() = 2, because today is tuesday.

```
var startDate = $('#jrange .input1').val();
var endDate = $('#jrange .input2').val();

var a = moment([startDate], 'DD-MM-YYYY');
var b = moment([endDate], 'DD-MM-YYYY');

//difference in days
var diffDays = b.diff(a, 'days');

//convert diff in month weeks and days

//if my range is between 2 and 7 days
if (diffDays >= 2 && diffDays <= 7) {
    $("#productRentLength").html("");

    //does the range contains saturday and sunday
    if (moment(diffDays).isoWeekday() == 6 && moment(diffDays).isoWeekday() == 7) {

        diffDays -= 2;

        var inDays = moment.duration(diffDays, "days").format("M [month] W [week(s)] D [days(s)] ");
        $("#productRentLength").text(inDays);
    }



} else {
    $("#productRentLength").html("");
    var inDays = moment.duration(diffDays, "days").format("M [month(s)] W [week(s)] D [days(s)]");
    $("#productRentLength").text(inDays);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it's not working"?

Comment: it seems that 
if (moment(diffDays).isoWeekday(6) == 6 && moment(diffDays).isoWeekday(7) == 7)

meens that is today saturday or sunday, it doesn't check inside diffDays

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to use `&&`, which means "and"? A day is never Saturday **and** Sunday at the same time. You probably wanted to use `||` (or) instead.

Comment: Yeah you're right, but I meant is there in diffDays a saturday AND a sunday

Comment: There's still something wrong with the logic in that `if` statement. `moment(diffDays).isoWeekday()` is not going to return 6 and also 7. I don't know momentJS but the way you're checking that is wrong.